# MS-Access : selecting data from two tables and only returning you need

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I've been stuck on this question all night and had to skip it, and come back to it (sorry I'm bit of a noob).

The question asks to display the course names and the names of the students who are only in those courses. I've tried `ORDER BY`, `GROUP BY` and `INNER JOIN` however `Course_Name` isn't present on both tables.

```
    SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Course_Name
    FROM  Student, Course
    ORDER BY Course_Name;
```

That's the closest I've been able to get, it returns ALL the students but lists them in ALL the courses, not just the courses they're in specifically which is what I'm after.

Any help? :)

I have two tables, `Course` and `Student`:

The `Course` has these columns:

```
Course_ID 
Course_Name
```

and the `Student` has

```
First_Name
Last_Name
Course_Name
```

Comment: You need to read up on `INNER JOIN`s, this could be of help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243855(v=office.12).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the courses list in Course table and students list in Student table, but you need to have one more table probably as CourseStudents which holds the data that represents which students take which courses.

Generally speaking (you may think of it as common practice) CourseStudents table consists of 2 columns: foreign key for Course table and foreign key for Student table.

Then you need a query like this:

```
SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Course_Name
FROM CourseStudents 
 INNER JOIN Student ON CourseStudents.StudentID = Student.StudentID
 INNER JOIN Course ON CourseStudents.CourseID = Course.CourseID
ORDER BY Course_Name
```

Comment: You are welcoma and yes probably your CourseStudent table name and ID field names inside were different as I made up the names above. If it solved your problem, please dont forget to mark it as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

i think that with this data structure, if you query only the 'student' table, you will get what you want (SELECT * FROM STUDENT).

this data structure allows 1 student to be at 1 course. probably you'd like to try to modify it as Noxthron said.

Table Student
   FirstName
   LastName
   StudentID

Table Course
   CourseName
   CourseID

Table CourseAssignment --> CourseStudents as said Noxthron
   StudentID
   CourseID